# selenium webdriver with javascript : how to allow chrome to download multiple files?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Looking around documents for hours like https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/

or

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

or

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

I was not able to find any workaround with selenium webdriver with javascript to allow multiple download files. Thought I could find such capabilities but I couldn't.

And I also tried this

```
await driver.switchTo().alert().accept()
await driver.executeScript("window.confirm = function(){return true}")
```

which didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try set the preference

```
var options = new chromeDriver.Options();
options.setUserPreferences({"profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads" : 1});
```